# Url class loading in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there a simple way to load a class from a URL in Ruby? I'm looking for something analogous to Java's URL class loader.

Example:

require 'http://github.com/outoftime/sunspot/blob/master/lib/light_config.rb'

- or -

require 'http://www.codehost.com/application.tgz' (signed archive containing multiple files?)

I'm considering adding a custom function to load the classes from the URL, perform security checks, then call something like eval(..) - but this approach seems a bit odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[http_require](http://blog.astrails.com/2009/5/12/ruby-http-require)

There's also a gem called [urirequire](http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=1057).  It appears to work:

http://yagni.com/bar.rb:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

def foo
  puts "foo"
end
```

foo.rb:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

require 'urirequire'
require 'http://yagni.com/bar.rb'

foo     # => foo
```